# Insert array value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I'm trying make array for `emp_no` from `empregtable` and to store array result into another table `message` (separate rows). I have code something like that. but it is not working. Please if anyone can help me on this, Thanks.

```
$selectresult = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT emp_no FROM empreg"); 
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectresult))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['emp_no'];
}
$values= serialize($_POST["emp_no"]);
foreach($values as $result)
{
    $sendmessage = mysqli_query ($dbc,"INSERT INTO message (to_user, date,message_title,message_contents) VALUES ('$values', '$date' ,'$subject','$message')");
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing. You are loading data from `empreg` into `$result_array` - but then you aren't using it anywhere. Then you are inserting the entire array from `$values` into the `message` table. Surely you meant to use this variable: `$result`?

Comment: hi Latheesan, it is inserting default value i.e (0) instead of array data.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$values as $result` but then don't use `$result`. Change `$values` to `$result` in your `foreach`.

e.g

```
    $values= serialize($_POST["custom"]);

    foreach($values as $result)
       {
          $sendmessage = mysqli_query ($dbc,"INSERT INTO message (to_user, date,message_title,message_contents) VALUES ('$result', '$date' ,'$subject','$message')");
       }                                                                                                                   ^---- here
```

Comment: hi Beat, i did what u told, but no luck. now no value is inserting in my database

Comment: Where do `$date`, `$subject` and `$message` come from? @SaurabhMosesRam

Comment: i created these variable to store current date, subject and message. subject and message is coming from <input> field and  $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

Comment: So what is the variable that isn't putting any data in? @SaurabhMosesRam

Comment: I have and array $result_array[] = $row['emp_no']; which is taking data from another table empreg. i want to insert array value to another table row i.e message.